# How to solve with each variable having an unique value?

Tags: equation-solving

I have a puzzle for example:

> Use 1 to 9, once only in the cells so that you obtain row and column products as shown:
>   [image]

```
mypuzzle2[val1_, val2_, val3_, val4_, val5_, val6_] :=  Solve[{a*b*c == val1, d*e*f == val2, g*h*i == val3, a*d*g == val4,    b*e*h == val5, c*f*i == val6, a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0, e > 0,    f > 0, g > 0, h > 0, i > 0, a < 10, b < 10, c < 10, d < 10, e < 10,     f < 10, g < 10, h < 10, i < 10}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i},   Integers]


mypuzzle2[80, 63, 72, 72, 48, 105]
```

[image]

How do I modify the code, so that it only returns with the answer with unique values of 1 to 9?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mypuzzle3[val__] /; Length[{val}] == 6 := Select[Permutations[Range @ 9], 
 With[{p = Partition[#, 3]}, Times @@@ Join[p, Transpose @ p] == {val}] &]

mypuzzle3[80, 63, 72, 72, 48, 105]
```

> {{2, 8, 5, 9, 1, 7, 4, 6, 3}}

Also:

```
Select[mypuzzle2[80, 63, 72, 72, 48, 105], Union[#[[All,-1]]]==Range[9]&]  (* or *)
Select[mypuzzle2[80, 63, 72, 72, 48, 105], DuplicateFreeQ[#[[All, -1]]] &]
```

> {{a -> 2, b -> 8, c -> 5, d -> 9, e -> 1, f -> 7, g -> 4, 
>     h -> 6,   i -> 3}}